# How to get AngularJS Validation working with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm having trouble with figuring out what I'm doing wrong with my form validation. I'm using the ng-show, and I think I'm referencing the form controls correctly, although I've never done this before (I'm new to AngularJS). I've followed several other examples here on SO, but somehow I'm still missing something. Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BkriRSFi62NtonzhIiW1?p=preview) of my code. In the Plunker, my error messages show up regardless of whether the fields have been entered. For some reason, running the code on localhost, the error messages don't show up at all.

Additionally, here is a portion of it:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email address (required):</label>
    <input id="emailAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="about.email" ng-pattern="about.emailFormat" required/>
    <span ng-show="contactForm.emailAddress.$dirty && contactForm.emailAddress.$error.pattern">Email is invalid</span>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('About', About);

function About() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.name = "";
    vm.email = "";
    vm.message = "";
    vm.emailFormat = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,10}$/;

    vm.sendMail = function () {
    };

    vm.cancel = function() {
        vm.name = "";
        vm.email = "";
        vm.message = "";
    };      
    return vm;
}})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a form with name attribute `contactForm`.You forgot the name attribute from form element.To access your input element, it should be `formName.inputName`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="emailAddress">Email address (required):</label>
                <input id="emailAddress"
                       name="emailAddress" type="text"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Email address"
                       ng-model="about.email"
                       ng-pattern="about.emailFormat"
                       required/>
                <span ng-show="contactForm.emailAddress.$dirty && contactForm.emailAddress.$error.pattern">Email is invalid</span>
            </div>
```

**Working Fiddle**: https://plnkr.co/edit/LIFcg3dRogw5yYgeuUac?p=preview

**For more Info** : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do form validation, you need to make use of the proper HTML tags, thus that's why it's not working as expected.

```
<form role="form" name="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email address (required):</label>
    <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" ng-model="about.email" ng-pattern="about.emailFormat" required/>
    <span ng-show="contactForm.emailAddress.$dirty && contactForm.emailAddress.$error.pattern">Email is invalid</span>
  </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: You were both correct - I'd forgotten the name attribute, though I'd looked at it time and time again, and seen the id attribute thinking it was name, somehow. Vivz was first, though I did upvote your answer. Thank you.